# php $_SESSION got mixed

Tags: php, session

I have a question about php $_SESSION.

Say i have a user A enter the index.php and it put some info,

```
$_SESSION['info'] = userA
```

Now user B enter the index.php and it put some other info,

```
$_SESSION['info'] = userB
```

Now in another test.php, what will it get when i call

```
$info=$_SESSION['info']
```

userA or userB?

Thanks!!

Comment: the session is unique for each user accessing the page.

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote, this can be an obvious curiosity of a beginner.

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath I totally agree with you. I dont know why seniors do quickly negative to new commers. It discourage them. They should be advised rather than giving negative. Negative vote should be for seniors

Comment: While I am not the downvoter, this *is* a question that could be answered by [reading the manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).  The way sessions work is explained in [the first three paragraphs of the introduction](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).  This implies that the manual was not referenced before asking.

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath was not me who downvoted it and I agree and upvoted it as soon as I saw that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the session is the same for both users, then user b will overwrite user a's value.

if the session is different for both users, you will get the value that the user you are logged in as.

if you have no session, then you will get nothing.

Comment: Sessions will *never* be "the same for both users."  That would be a security nightmare.

Comment: @Charles in theory that is true, but what if two users login using the same browser on the same computer, and the sessions doesn't get reset for whatever reason. without seeing the codebase there is no guarantee

Comment: two people using one browser on one computer -- at the same time -- would only appear to PHP as one user with one session.  You'd have userA or userB, not some sort of bizarre wtfery involving both users.

Comment: @charles, as per my answer "if the session is the same for both users, then user b will overwrite user a's value." not sure where the wtfery comes into it

Answer (score 3):

Output will be related to user of current session.

Different session is created for each user.

Answer (score 1):

My dear session is seperate for both users. For User A it has its seperate copy and value and for User B it has its own. So You dont need to worry about mixer.

Answer (score 1):

Separate sessions are created in the server for every user (accessing using different browsers or computers) and they are associated with every user using unique SESSION IDs, which are either stored as a cookie in the browser or are passed in the URL.

So, when user A logs in from one browser/computer, a unique SESSION ID associates it to its session value stored in the server and when user B logs in, another SESSION ID associates it to its own session value. So, although the server *keeps both the session values in memory at a time*, the users see only their own SESSION value. There is no mix up.